# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command

Tags: automation, bdd, appium, specflow, appium-ios

Facing this error while executing in appium.

Appearing as a random error whenever appium is waiting for any element to disappear.

```
int counter = 0;
            while (MyRecentSubmissions.IsStatusPending() && (++counter < 60))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            if(counter==60)
                Assert.IsTrue(!MyRecentSubmissions.IsStatusPending());
```

Whenever it's waiting and element disappears and the test case moves forward to next step.. Then while processing next step I am getting the above mentioned error.

I have around 40 scenarios which is using both the steps and randomly 2-4 scenarios fail and above error is displayed.

Is there any specific reason for appium to behave in such a manner??

Using Appium, iOS application, C# as development language
Any solution. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Edit : Logs for failure are :

> System.InvalidOperationException : An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary'2 parameters) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click() at
>   GEHealthcare.MM.Test.AutomationFramework.TableCell.TapCellByXPath(String
>   locator) in
>   d:\depot\NGI\PRDS\MediaM\2016\1\DEV\Red_Gold\MediaManagerSystemTest\AutomationFramework\UIElements\TableCell.cs:line
>   18 at
>   GEHealthcare.MM.Test.BusinessLogic.MyRecentSubmissions.TapTableCell()
>   in
>   d:\depot\NGI\PRDS\MediaM\2016\1\DEV\Red_Gold\MediaManagerSystemTest\BusinessLogic\MyRecentSubmissions\MyRecentSubmissions.cs:line
>   35 at
>   GEHealthcare.MM.Test.MyRecentSubmissionsSteps.WhenISelectTheSubmissionFromMyRecentSubmissionsScreen()
>   in
>   d:\depot\NGI\PRDS\MediaM\2016\1\DEV\Red_Gold\MediaManagerSystemTest\MediaManager.Test\StepDefinations\MyRecentSubmissionsSteps.cs:line
>   39 at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager ) at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding
>   binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments,
>   ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration) at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch
>   match, Object[] arguments) at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance
>   stepInstance) at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
>   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors() at
>   MediaManager.Test.Features.ImageAttributesWithFreeTextFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
>   in
>   d:\depot\NGI\PRDS\MediaM\2016\1\DEV\Red_Gold\MediaManagerSystemTest\MediaManager.Test\Features\ImageAttributesWithFreeText.feature.cs:line
>   0 at
>   MediaManager.Test.Features.ImageAttributesWithFreeTextFeature.TC_129_VerifySubmissionDetailsWithFreeTextImageAttributes()
>   in
>   d:\depot\NGI\PRDS\MediaM\2016\1\DEV\Red_Gold\MediaManagerSystemTest\MediaManager.Test\Features\ImageAttributesWithFreeText.feature:line
>   7

Comment: While your test --> check for disappearance is in progress, can you hit this url http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/sessions in browser and see if you get any response and if yes, then are you getting any value in values key of received json response in browser, if there is no response then chromedriver is dead and if there is no value in Value key in received json response then chromedriver is hanged then you need to write a code  to monitor chromedriver!!

Comment: could you share the logs for better understanding of the problem

Comment: @PankajKatiyar I am facing this issue in nightly execution of my batch.. Also, I have an iOS app to test. Not a specific error or so.. Not facing this issue in same TC always. Randomly error is appearing anywhere in suite

Comment: @nullpointer - new to stackoverflow.. Don't know how to attach a log with comments. Please bare..

Comment: use wepaste.com/123456

Comment: @SurajGupta : add it to your question itself and then you can remove those comments, shall make sense.

Comment: @PankajKatiyar Thanks for the solution..

Comment: @nullpointer - [log error](http://www.wepaste.com/appium%20log%20for%20unknown%20server%20side%20error/)

Here is the link